# What is the _intended_ value of &?ROUTINE?

Tags: raku, compile-time, rakudo

The Rakudo implementation of Raku tracks multiple issues about the (very useful!) &?ROUTINE variable not providing the correct value (e.g., [#1768](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1768) and [2362](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2362)), so I realize that it's not behaving quite correctly.  But I'm trying to understand what it's *intended* behavior is – which seems like an essential first step in fixing that behavior.

Running this code with Rakudo v2021.06 produces the output noted in the comments.  Which parts of this output are correct, and which represent bugs?

```
sub foo  {
    note '## ifs:';
    do if True { say &?ROUTINE.name }                # OUTPUT: «foo»
    if True    { say &?ROUTINE.name }                # OUTPUT: «<unit>»

    note '## ifs w/ topic:';
    do if True -> $a { say $a; say &?ROUTINE.name }  # OUTPUT: «True», # OUTPUT«""»
    if True -> $a    { say $a; say &?ROUTINE.name }  # OUTPUT: «True», # OUTPUT«foo»
    
    note '## fors:';
    for 1 { say &?ROUTINE.name }                     # OUTPUT: «foo»
    say &?ROUTINE.name for 1;                        # OUTPUT: «""»

    note '## methods:';
    42.&{              say &?ROUTINE.name }          # OUTPUT: «foo»
    my method m($a:) { say &?ROUTINE.name }
    42.&m;                                           # OUTPUT: «m»
}
foo
```

The [relevant docs](https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#&?ROUTINE) say that &?ROUTINE returns "an instance of Sub", which makes it sound like all of the above should be 'foo'.  On the other hand, a Method is a Routine, so I'm somewhat inclined to think that the last two (an anonymous method and a named method) should *not* be 'foo'.  I'm also unsure whether all the '' and "" values represent bugs, or if there's a principle at work that makes some (or all?) of those intended behavior.

(I also tested the above code with the `use soft` pragma to make sure that inlining wasn't having an effect that I could fix with that pragma; it had no effect on the output)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `&?ROUTINE` symbol should evaluate to an object representing the nearest lexically enclosing routine - that is, the nearest enclosing declaration of type `Routine`. This includes both `Sub` and `Method`. Furthermore, given these are all in principle closures, it should evaluate to the correct closure clone of the routine.

Thus a correct implementation would produce:

```
sub foo  {
    note '## ifs:';
    do if True { say &?ROUTINE.name }                # OUTPUT: «foo»
    if True    { say &?ROUTINE.name }                # OUTPUT: «foo»

    note '## ifs w/ topic:';
    do if True -> $a { say $a; say &?ROUTINE.name }  # OUTPUT: «True», # OUTPUT«foo»
    if True -> $a    { say $a; say &?ROUTINE.name }  # OUTPUT: «True», # OUTPUT«foo»
    
    note '## fors:';
    for 1 { say &?ROUTINE.name }                     # OUTPUT: «foo»
    say &?ROUTINE.name for 1;                        # OUTPUT: «foo»

    note '## methods:';
    42.&{              say &?ROUTINE.name }          # OUTPUT: «foo»
    my method m($a:) { say &?ROUTINE.name }
    42.&m;                                           # OUTPUT: «m»
}
foo
```

Current Rakudo is thus getting this wrong in a number of cases. Despite having worked extensively on the compiler, I don't have a good guess what it's doing here; I do know that I won't be copying the current implementation when I get to adding `&?ROUTINE` support in the new compiler frontend that I'm working on!

Comment: Very informative, thanks.  I'd always thought that the syntax `42.&{???}` created an anonymous method, but your answer and some tests in the REPL made me realize that it  instead calls a Block using method _syntax_ but not as a method object.  I've submitted a doc PR to clarify that point.

Comment: @codesections The `{…}` **is** the anonymous block. Whenever you see `{…}` it creates an anonymous block. Since there is no `method` keyword to turn that anonymous block into a method, it isn't a method.

Answer (score 6):

Per @Larry's spec<sup>**[1]**</sup>:

> `&?ROUTINE` is always an alias for the lexically innermost `Routine` (which may be a `Sub`, `Method`, or `Submethod`) ...
>
> You can get the current routine name by calling `&?ROUTINE.name`. Outside of any [routine] declaration, this call returns failure.
>
> Note that `&?ROUTINE` refers to the current single [routine], even if it is declared `multi`. To redispatch to the entire suite under a given short name, just use the named form to call the proto, since there are no anonymous `multi`s.

## Footnotes

<sup>**[1]**</sup> "@Larry" is/was historical shorthand for the evolving de facto Raku design team. "spec" is/was historical shorthand for the evolving design. The above quotes are from S06 section [**The &?ROUTINE object**](https://design.raku.org/S06.html#The_%26%3FROUTINE_object)